# If else statement not running what could be the error

Tags: c, if-statement

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(){
    int length,breadth,perimeter,area;
    printf("Enter the length and breadth of the rectangle respectively\n");
    scanf("%d%d", length, breadth);
    area = length*breadth;
    perimeter = length + breadth + length + breadth;
    if (area>perimeter)
    {
        printf("The area is greater than the perimeter\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("The area is equal to or greater than the perimeter\n");
    }
    

    return 0;
}
```

I can put values of length and breadth but the if condition is not running program closes after input

Comment: What do the warnings from your compiler say?

Comment: Welcome! If you enable compiler warnings, you should see that `scanf("%d%d", length, breadth);` must be `scanf("%d%d", &length, &breadth);`

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to look at your compiler warnings and errors. It should tell you that `scanf` expects parameters of type `int*` as argument for `%d` format specifier. You are passing (uninitialized) integer variables. That causes undefined behaviour

Comment: Read what `%d` expect in argument for `scanf()`.

Comment: If your compiler does not warn you for wrong parameter type, it should at least warn about using `length` and `breadth` without assigning a value to it which also causes undefined behaviour. You might need to increase warning level for your compiler. For gcc or clang use options `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

Comment: Finally, that is a good time to start using a debugger. Run your program in a debugger, step through the code and inspect values of all involved variables. That will show you immediately that your input did not end up in any variable. Also.... You should always check return value of `scanf`. Otherwise you cannot detect if some wrong input was provided.

Comment: You got two good answers.  Please accept the best one by clicking on the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 2):

`scanf()` requires the address of your variables.  You should also check the return value (`rv`) to ensure two variables are successfully read:

```
    int rv = scanf("%d%d", &length, &breadth);
    if(rv != 2) {
        printf("error\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the scanf function call. When using scanf to read input, you need to pass the address of the variables where the input should be stored using the & symbol.
I have corrected your code, Below is the corrected code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(){
    int length,breadth,perimeter,area;
    // printf("Enter the length and breadth of the rectangle respectively\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &length, &breadth);
    area = length*breadth;
    perimeter = 2 * (length+breadth);

    if (area>perimeter)
    {
        printf("The area is greater than the perimeter\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("The area is equal to or smaller than the perimeter\n");
    }
    

    return 0;
}
```